# Calling startActivityForResult from a different class?

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I have a Drawer that slide from the left in my Activity. I normally call `startActivityForResult` from a Button click and this normally works fine. The button is instantiated in my Activity so `startActivityForResult` and onActivityResult work fine.

Since i have implemented the Drawer and call `startActivityForResult` (which boots up the camera) from the selectItem method, the camera does not start.
I think the reason for this is because `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult` need to be in the same class for the mechanism to work.

How can i call `startActivityForResult` from my Drawer and send the result to my outer Activity.

Thanks in advance.

```
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
                Log.e(TAG, "in onActivityResult");
                if (requestCode == 0) {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "result ok");

        }
        ......

        private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    String rowTitle = view.getTag().toString();

                    selectItem(position, rowTitle);

                }


            }

            /** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
            private void selectItem(int position, String rowTitle) {




                // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                //setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

                //"SIGN IN/OUT", "SEND OUTSTANDING TRANSACTIONS", "SIGNOUT MANUALLY", "LOGS", "ASSESSMENTS"

                if(rowTitle.equalsIgnoreCase("SIGN IN/OUT")){

                                    Log.e(TAG, "onclicked sign in");

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.carefreegroup.rr3.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE","QR_CODE_MODE");            
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
```

.
EDIT1

```
adapter2 = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, lst2);

mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter2);
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```

Comment: java's(or even OOP) basics ... startActivityForResult  is a method of some class ... you need instance of this class to call it ... where is a problem?

Comment: @Selvin I do create an instance in my Activity and i call startActivityForResult from with the DrawerItemClickListener which is a different class. the onActivityResult is not called as in a different class

Comment: Did you called setResult() and finish() on the opened Activity?

Comment: @ZsoltBoldizsár no i don't, where would i call those and why? thanks

Comment: @turtleboy Take a look at my answer, hope it'll help you.

Comment: @ZsoltBoldizsár Hi i have had a look, but my activity calls the ZXing library code. ZXing is a bar scanner application. i've had a look at the CaptureActivity code and there is no call to finish() and the only setResult is when the camera/scanner is cancelled. It works fine if i call the scanner library from my onCreate, just not from the Drawer

Comment: @ZsoltBoldizsár are you saying that the called Activity should not call setResult and finish for the calling Activity to receive the result?

Comment: @turtleboy No, I say exactly the opposite. I'm not familiar to ZXing though. But the concept of startActivityForResult is as described in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)) to start an activity should be used to do some work on that new activity, and return the result to the caller by calling the [setResult(int resultCode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int)) or [setResult(int resultCode, Intent data)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent)) method.

> For example, your app can start a camera app and receive the captured photo as a result. Or, you might start the People app in order for the user to select a contact and you'll receive the contact details as a result.

So until you don't call `setResult()` and `finish()` on the new activity, your caller activity will never receive the result on it's `onActivityResult()` callback.

You should definitely read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) for a thorough explanation.
Also consider reading [this article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html) as well.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Boldizsar Hi i've accepted your answer because in what you have suggested is correct and will help most people. I checked and i do indeed call setresult() and finish(), so after a couple of days of trying different things, i remembered that i had changed the launch mode of my calling activity to android:launchMode="singleTask" 
            android:noHistory="true" this is why the onActivityResult was never called in my Activity as it had been popped of the stack. Thanks for you help.

Comment: I'd made those launch mode changes several months ago, so was not fresh in mind. One of those hard to solve as it is not apparent :)